# ShareKit opens Official Facebook App on iPad when sharing?

Tags: ios, facebook, sharekit

Just when I thought I had sorted it another problem occurs! So I finally got ShareKit to share an image on Facebook (clicking on Share Facebook button, which then opens mobile Safari to authenticate, then goes back to app and saves image to Facebook....cool)but after much research I'm sure I read somewhere that if you had the official Facebook app on your device, mobile Safari would't need to launch to authenticate. So I decided to download the Official Facebook app and give it a go.

Now when I tap on my Facebook share button, rather than Safari launching to authenticate, the official Facebook App launches, shows some blank pop up window saying 'Connecting' then goes back to my app and does absolutely nothing at all.

So in other words I can get it to work if I don't have the Official Facebook app installed on my device but it doesn't work if I do!!!

Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: You aren't handling the authentication properly.  Without any code, it is hard to tell what you are doing wrong.

Comment: I thought it was share kit that dealt with the authentication?

Comment: Since we cannot see any of your code, it's hard to tell.  It really sounds like an issue you need to contact sharekit support for.  http://getsharekit.com/support/

Answer (score 1):

First, In Xcode, you need to change your apps bundle ID from the default which includes $PRODUCT_NAME... to the actual name of your app so it looks like: com.domain.appname

Second, make sure the bundle ID for your app on FB matches your fully qualified bundle ID.

Third, make sure that SSO is enabled in your Facebook APP settings.